# With indentation set to `0em`, when using a line break, there is still an indentation of a size of a space

Tags: luatex, indentation

### Problem Description

I am quite a newbie at *TeX, but I defined some `\newcommand`s as some kind of paragraph styles (maybe not the proper way to do so, maybe someone could tell me how to accomplish this better).

I want to have default paragraph style with no indentation, space after paragraph should be 0.08", space before paragraph should be 0". However, any of the paragraph style could change any of these settings and some something more (like character styles, e.g. bold, italics, underline, etc).

Now, sometimes I want to insert a paragraph in particular paragraph style *without* space after that paragraph. For that I use line break (`\\`), which usually does the job. However, with the `\paragraphStyle` below, this is broken.

It seems like if in the first paragraph, there is an indentation of a size of a space, which I cannot elimininate, no matter what I do.

### What I have Tried

I tried to use `\noindent` and `\setlength{\parindent}{0em}` in many different combinations.

### Minimal Working Example

```
%%%%%  Preamble  %%%%%
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=1in,
    right=1in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
    portrait
}

\usepackage{xcolor}

% Font family
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

% Paragraph and line settings
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}           % Set paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}          % Paragraph spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}  % Line \expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\cvlang}

% Custom commands
\newcommand{\paragraphStyle}[1]{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0.16in}\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}\color{black!100}\fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont{\textbf{#1}}\color{black!100}\normalsize\setlength{\parindent}{0em}\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}\selectfont\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    This is wrong:

    \paragraphStyle{
        First line\\
        Second line
    }

    This is correct:

    \paragraphStyle{First line}\\
    \paragraphStyle{Second line}


    Also this is correct in indentation, but not in space after paragraph:

    First Line\\
    Second Line
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: this is really a very strange definition you are setting parindent and parskip hidden inside `\pargraphStyle` but they are not in any local group so they apply to the rest of the document not just the text in the argument. I would seriously consider _not_ using this markup and using a more normal latex constrict.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, what do you advise to do? How should I define styles *correctly*? What markup should I use?

Comment: You don't give any indication of the intended use, what is this large text for, is it some kind of heading? It is hard to suggest a reasonable markup with the information given.

Comment: This particular style is a text body paragraph with large(r) font size for easier readability. In the end, I’d like to create more styles (just imagine those of any word processor like LibreOffice Writer or MS Office Word). Anyway, [here](https://gitlab.com/tukusejssirs/lit_scores/blob/5cf9d338093778ddcba9885438f02dc2cb4b63bb/misal_velka_noc/misal_velka_noc.pdf)’s an actual pdf I am currenly working on—I’d like to create a style for all different styles I need to create that file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Marcel pointed out, there is a stray space in your input.  You can remove that space, as Marcel suggests, or you can add `\ignorespaces`, *within your macro definition*, to your argument of `\textbf`, prior to `#1`.  Also, there is no need for the `\textbf{}` to be in its own braces, so I removed it.

Note: an alternative for that part of the definition that now reads `\textbf{\ignorespaces#1}` could also be `{\bfseries#1}`.  Here, the braces are now necessary to limit the scope, but the `\ignorespaces` is no longer required *because `\bfseries` leaves you in vertical mode, so the leading space in `#1` is ignored, whereas `\textbf{}` puts you in horizontal mode, where the leading space counts*.

Also, I reorganized your definition of `\paragraphStyle` to make it easier for humans to read.  Note the presence of `%` end-of-line delimiters, to avoid the very same problem again.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=1in,
    right=1in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
    portrait
}

\usepackage{xcolor}

% Font family
%\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright]{unicode-math}
%\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

% Paragraph and line settings
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}           % Set paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}          % Paragraph spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}  % Line \expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\cvlang}

% Custom commands
\newcommand{\paragraphStyle}[1]{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0.16in}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}%
  \color{black!100}%
  \fontsize{20pt}{24pt}%
  \selectfont%
  \textbf{\ignorespaces#1}%
  \color{black!100}%
  \normalsize%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0em}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}%
  \selectfont%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}%
}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    This is no longer wrong:

    \paragraphStyle{
        First line\\
        Second line
    }

    This is correct:

    \paragraphStyle{First line}\\
    \paragraphStyle{Second line}


    Also this is correct in indentation, but not in space after paragraph:

    First Line\\
    Second Line
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\ignorespaces is no longer required, because the space is absorbed in the aftermath of the macro \bfseries` no:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why do you say that?  `\bfseries<space><space><space><etc>          #1` also produces no introduced spaces.  What's the right terminology to describe this process?

Comment: `\ignorespaces` was there to ignore spaces that are passed in at the start of `#1` they would not be dropped in the way that a literal space after `\bfseries` is dropped.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK... But they are nonetheless dropped.  Why?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it a vertical/horizontal mode thing?  That is, does `\bfseries` not take one out of vertical mode?  Whereas `\textbf{}` does?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Confirmed...it is a vertical mode thing.

Comment: yes I was going to say `\textbf` starts the paragraph so spaces are get typeset, `\bfseries` does not so the space tokens are still made but are ignored, with `\ignorespaces` there are no space tokens. So in context you were right that `\ignorespaces` would not be needed, but wrong for the reason. call it a draw:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found `\bfseries\leavevmode#1` indeed puts the space back in.  That's how I knew.

Comment: Thank you all for all the insight. :) Still I need to google more info about what those horizontal/vertical modes. However, I’d like to know if this way is the correct *Tex way to define a style. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @tukusejssirs Think of horizontal mode as building the contents of a paragraph (e.g., indents, justifications, word wrapping, etc), and vertical mode as laying out a collection of paragraphs on the page (e.g., vertical gaps, locating floats, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

The "indentation of a size of a space" actually isn't an indentation, it is a space at the start of the line:

Look at

```
    This is wrong:

    \paragraphStyle{
        First line\\
        Second line
    }
```

The newline after `\paragraphStyle{` is converted to a space which results in the observed "indentation".
You can avoid this by adding a `%` to comment the newline, suppressing the space:

```
    This is wrong:

    \paragraphStyle{%
        First line\\
        Second line
    }
```

The full document becomes

```
%%%%%  Preamble  %%%%%
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=1in,
    right=1in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
    portrait
}

\usepackage{xcolor}

% Font family
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

% Paragraph and line settings
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}           % Set paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}          % Paragraph spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}  % Line \expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\cvlang}

% Custom commands
\newcommand{\paragraphStyle}[1]{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0.16in}\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}\color{black!100}\fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont{\textbf{#1}}\color{black!100}\normalsize\setlength{\parindent}{0em}\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}\selectfont\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    This is wrong:

    \paragraphStyle{%
        First line\\
        Second line
    }

    This is correct:

    \paragraphStyle{First line}\\
    \paragraphStyle{Second line}


    Also this is correct in indentation, but not in space after paragraph:

    First Line\\
    Second Line
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use grouping to isolate the changes in font and line spacing, so you don't have to revert them afterwards. However, since these changes have to be done, you need to end the previous paragraph, if not already done and also to end a paragraph at the end of the special setup, so as not to influence the following paragraphs.

```latex
%%%%%  Preamble  %%%%%
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=1in,
    right=1in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
    portrait,
}

\usepackage{xcolor}

% Font family
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

% Paragraph and line settings
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}           % Set paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}          % Paragraph spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}  % Line 

% Custom commands
\newcommand{\paragraphStyle}[1]{%
  \par
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0.16in}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}%
  \fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont
  \noindent\color{black!100}%
  \bfseries\ignorespaces #1\par
  \endgroup
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

This is right:

\paragraphStyle{
  First line\\
  Second line
}

Also this is correct in indentation, but not in space after paragraph:

First Line\\
Second Line

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. All three of you has a bit of information I need to incorporate into the document, that is (1) in the `\newcommand`, I need to add a group; (2) beware of ‘stray spaces’ (newlines converted into spaces).

Comment: @egrep, could you check my updated question, please? :)

Comment: @tukusejssirs Please, note that my nickname is not *egrep*. Just remove the ``\\``, that does nothing after `\par` besides raising an error: ``\paragraphStyle{First line}\\`` should be `\paragraphStyle{First line}`. Then roll back your question removing the last edit.

Comment: I apologise for misspelling your nickname. :) … Yes, I’ve just found the very same behaviour. Is there another way to make it work with `\\` without another ‘instance’ of `\paragraphStyle`?

Comment: And it does not align the right side of the first line of the second paragraph in this code: `\paragraphStyle{Bratia a sestry, v tuto presvatu noc nas Pan Jezis Kristus vstal z mrtvych. Preto Cirkev po celom svet zvolava svojich synov a dcery a zhromazduje ich, aby bedlili a modlili sa. Aj my sme prijali toto pozvanie.\n\nPripomenieme si Panovo zmrtvychvstanie, budeme pocuvat Bozie slovo a oslavime velkonocne tajomstvo v nadeji, ze budeme mat podiel na Kristovom vitazstve nad smrtou a na jeho zivote v Bohu.}`.

Comment: I’d like to have a *paragraph style* just like in word processor. But this code probably lacks the ability to set the paragraph style of the next paragraph (in the example of my previous comment the second one, however in general, it should be the nth paragraph). All paragraphs in braced in `\paragraphStyle{}` should have the same paragraph and/or character style. However, when I use `\par` in the command definition, this cannot work (at least not in the current version).

Comment: Update: when I use the original text with diacritics, the overflow into the right margin happens even in the second row of the first paragraph: `\paragraphStyle{Bratia a sestry, v túto presvätú noc náš Pán Ježiš Kristus vstal z mŕtvych. Preto Cirkev po celom svete zvoláva svojich synov a dcéry a zhromažďuje ich, aby bedlili a modlili sa. Aj my sme prijali toto pozvanie.\n\nPripomenieme si Pánovo zmŕtvychvstanie, budeme počúvať Božie slovo a oslávime veľkonočné tajomstvo v nádeji, že budeme mať podiel na Kristovom víťazstve nad smrťou a na jeho živote v Bohu.}`

Comment: This is also true with the text without diacritics too, but by mistake I removed the final "e" in the word "svete" there.

Comment: @tukusejssirs Are you adding `\usepackage[slovak]{babel}`? If I do and also add `\usepackage{microtype}`, I get no overfull box message.

Comment: I am using `babel`, but never used `microtype`. Still, the right side is not aligned. LuaLaTeX code is [here](https://pastebin.com/0F3Y4Luv), output [here](https://imgur.com/fdHxN6k).

Comment: LuaLaTex compiles it wrong, however, XeLaTex is perfect (with and without `microtype`).

Comment: @tukusejssirs The microtype bug seems to have been fixed in the forthcoming release of TeX Live.